# Will the compiler ever use the move constructor to move a named variable that is about to go out of scope?

Tags: c++, compilation, move-semantics

consider function void foo() and class myclass

```
class myclass { /* some data members, including pointers, and a move constructor */ };

void foo()
{
   myclass myvar = myclass(...);    // foo() allocates space on the stack for sdlv
                                    // then passes address in %rdi to constructor

   /* myvar is used a few times */

   myclass myvar_copy = myvar;      // myvar used for the last time
   return;
}
```

myvar is an lvalue, but when it is used for the final time, it might as well be a reference to a rvalue (&&).  A C++ compiler will detect a typical && (like x * y) by recognizing that (x * y) is a temporary object.  Will a C++ compiler (say gcc) intelligently know to use a move constructor in the example above too?

Comment: `myvar` is an lvalue and so the move ctor cannot be used because it's parameter is `myclass&&` which cannot be bound to an lvalue. Thus the copy constructor is used, as its parameter is `const myclass&` which can bound to an lvalue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myclass myvar_copy = myvar;`  is *copy initialization* where `myvar` is an lvalue. The copy constructor has a parameter of type `const myclass&` and the move constructor has a parameter of type `myclass&&`.

Now, since the argument that we're passing is `myvar` which is an lvalue only the copy constructor can be used since the move constructor parameter is `myclass&&`  which cannot be bound to an lvalue.

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly move (shallow copy) the contents of myvar to myvar_copy knowing myvar won't be used again?

Comment: @JohnFisher You can write `myclass myvar_copy = std::move(myvar);`. Now the move ctor will be used(if available for your class).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is allowed to do any optimization, that does not influence the program's side effects. This is called the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). There are very few exceptions to that rule, from which [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is one. The rules for copy elision don't apply in your example, thus the compiler is not allowed to change the side effects of the program by optimizing. Your program will behave **as if** the copy constructor is called.